# CABasicAnimation not animating on CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation

Core Animation documentation seems simple enough, yet I can't figure out what's missing. I have a CAShapeLayer that I would like to animate using a simple CABasicAnimation.

I build the CAShapeLayer like so:

```
{
 CGRect rect = CGRectMake(focal.x, focal.y, (self.radius * 2), (self.radius * 2));

 self.touchCircle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
 [self.touchCircle setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect] CGPath]];
 [self.touchCircle setFrame:rect];
 [self.touchCircle setLineWidth:self.stroke];
 [self.touchCircle setPosition:focal];

 [self focalColorOfPoint:focal];

 [self.layer addSublayer:self.touchCircle];
}
```

and attempt an animation:

```
CABasicAnimation *radiusScale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"size"];

[radiusScale setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(self.mRadius, self.mRadius)]];
[radiusScale setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(self.radius, self.radius)]];
[radiusScale setDuration:0.3f];

[self.touchCircle addAnimation:radiusScale forKey:@"touchCircleRadiusScaleUp"];
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is "size" a custom animateble property of yours?

Comment: no, it's specified by the list of key-value paths I found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH12-SW2

Comment: I think you are misreading the documentation. The correct keypath is `@"bounds.size"`

Answer (score 1):

Try using animationWithKeyPath:@"transform" and animate

```
.toValue=[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ)];
```